# Can you disable the welcome message that shows when a chrome extension is first installed?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Whenever a chrome extension is installed, Chrome shows a welcome message popup:

[image: Chrome Extension Welcome Message]

Is there any way for this to be disabled when building the extension?

Comment: I can't think of any legitimate reason to do this. In fact, the only thing I can come up with is that you have some malicious extension that you are trying to deliver and want to conceal that from the user.

Comment: It's part of our registration flow, and after asking a user to install our extension, we need them to login to their account before continuing. The welcome message blocks some UI arrows on the page pointing them to do that.

Answer (score 4):

I believe there is no way to do this, since obviously it's the default behavior of chrome, which means to let user know there is a new extension installed, how to manage extensions and to prevent extension is silently installed in background.

When building extension by ourselves, we can do something when extension is first installed, by listening to [chrome.runtime.onInstalled](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled) event, usually we will popup a web page or navigate user to specific sites. However, we can determine if we need this behavior, but we can't change the default behavior of chrome browser extension.

Answer (score 0):

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {...});
```

Source [developer.chrome.com](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled)

I do believe that this is a good place to start.